# Spring-Data-JPA paging

Tags: java, spring, jpql, spring-data-jpa

I am using the [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin to display a List of orderpositions.
While debugging my application I stumbled upon the following inconsistency.

To retrieve the data, I used the `@Query`-Notation for my custom query:

```
@Query("select op from OrderPosition  " +
        "op where op.order.created >= ?1" +
        " and op.depot in ?2" +
        " and op.order.deliveryAddress.deliveryMode in ?3" +
        " and op.pickStatus in ?4 and op.order.id like ?5 ")
Page<OrderPosition> findOrderpositionsByFilterStatus(Date date, List<Integer>depots, List<DeliveryMode> deliveryModes, List<ArticleStatusType> pickStatus, String sSearch, Pageable p);
```

The error occured is the following:

I have a set of 81 Orderpositions test data. In the frontend I am able to filter by several criteria. One of the criteria is the `deliveryMode` (express|standard). I display 10 Entries at a time. The total number of `express`deliveries is 6. When paging through the  Pages only 2 `express` are displayed. When filtering explicitely on `express` I get all 6.

When I add some sort of ordering e.g:

```
@Query("select op from OrderPosition  " +
        "op where op.order.created >= ?1" +
        " and op.depot in ?2" +
        " and op.order.deliveryAddress.deliveryMode in ?3" +
        " and op.pickStatus in ?4 and op.order.id like ?5 " +
        "order by op.order.id desc")
Page<OrderPosition> findOrderpositionsByFilterStatus(Date date, List<Integer>depots, List<DeliveryMode> deliveryModes, List<ArticleStatusType> pickStatus, String sSearch, Pageable p);
```

I get all 6 of 'em.

What brings me to the question:

When using non annotated queries - either the generic `findAll()` or queries from method names- does Spring-Data-JPA use an `order by`-clause internally, when detecting a `pageable`? Or inverse: Do I have to add an `order by`-clause in each of my custom queries, when using a `pageable`?

Comment: Is it really relevant to include Datatables in the question? Even if you discovered the bug thanks to it, it seems like a JPA/Spring-Data-JPA question to me.

Comment: You can enable log to see the generated sql and verify it.

Comment: Can you edit and post your resolution? What did your query and Page looked like?

Comment: @Blejzer I would. But unfortunately I do not work at the company anymore - I do not have access to the code.

Comment: Darn! I thought you would be my savior!!! :D

Comment: @Blejzer You are just a few days to late - left by last thursday, starting tomorrow my new occupation; off by one error - so to say ;)

Comment: Well, good luck with your new endeavour! I'll just ask it again here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes inded. Spring Data uses an `OrderBy` (with a default desc) if you do not specify further.
Look at the Logs:

```
SELECT t0.oid, t0.jpaversion, t0.amount, [...]
FROM [...]
WHERE [..] AND (t13.jpatype IS NULL OR t13.jpatype IN (?))
ORDER BY t0.oid DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```